# How to access a class attribute using a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to know how can I access a class attribute using a string. E.g

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        # defined self.name here
        self.name.person = 1
```

If I have the program:

```
a = "person" 
b = Test()
```

How can I print self.name.person using the variable a?

```
print(b.name.a)
```

Many thanks!

Comment: of course self.name is already defined

Answer (score 1):

Python has `getattr()` as built-in function:

```
print(getattr(b.name, a))
```